Reuseable Like Button Jquery Script
I designed a like button which uses a script to toggle the appearance of the like button image and also record the result on my database. It works fine but the way I designed it means the script is duplicated for every like button. I am trying to figure out a way to only have the script once on my page.
HTML
The html creates the button on page load. $users5 is a variable (integer) which is different for every like button and it's associated script. $users5 is concatenated to Show and Hide for the div ID. Clicking on the div starts the script.
<div id="hide'.$users5.'"style="display:none"><img src="unlovesm.png"></div>
<div id="show'.$users5.'"><img src="lovesm.png"></div><br>

JQuery
Depending on which "like" image is visible, the Jquery will hide that one and show the other one. And save the result with insert.php
$(document).ready(function(){
    

  $("#hide$users5").click(function(){
    
       var liked = "liked";
     var image = '$users2';
     var user = '$user2';
       $.ajax({
                    url:'insert.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{
                       
                        liked:liked,
                        user:user,
                        image:image
                    },
                   success:function(data){
                         $("#hide$users5").hide();
                         $("#show$users5").show();
                       

                   }
                });
  });
  $("#show$users5").click(function(){
     
       var liked = "unliked";
        var image = '$users2';
         var user = '$user2';
       $.ajax({
                    url:'insert.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{
                        
                        liked:liked,
                         user:user,
                        image:image
                    },
                   success:function(data){
                      $("#hide$users5").show();
                      $("#show$users5").hide();
 
                       
                   }
                });
  });
  

});

I think I need something like onclick="myFunction('$users5')" to send the variable to the script but some expert help is required.
I'm pretty useless at JQuery that's why my like button ended up so weird.

AL W "If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's How does accepting an answer work?. Then return here and do the same with the tick/check-mark till it turns green. This informs the community, that a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!"

a) You need to use the class concept to do it with one handler. Add a common class to each button say like-dislike
b) Add corresponding data-* attribute for like/dislike images.
example:
data-type="liked" //for like image
data-type="unliked"//for unlike image

c) Add other data-* attributes to get other values if required
So it will be like this:
<div class="like-dislike" data-type="unliked" data-image="users-2" data-user="user-2" style="display:none;">
  <img src="unlovesm.png">unlovesm.png
</div>
<div class="like-dislike" data-type="liked" data-image="users-2" data-user="user-2">
  <img src="lovesm.png">lovesm.png
</div>
<br>

Now jQuery code will be simplified with a single code like this :
$(function(){
    $(".like-dislike").click(function(){
        var obj = $(this); //save $(this) to a variable so that you can use it in Ajax success
        var liked = obj.data('type')=='unliked' ? 'unliked':'liked';
        var image = obj.data('image');
        var user = obj.data('user');
        $.ajax({
            url:'insert.php',
            method:'POST',
            data:{
                liked:liked,
                user:user,
                image:image
            },
            success:function(data){
                obj.hide();
                obj.siblings('.like-dislike').show();
            }
        });
    });
});

Sample working snippet without ajax:


$(".like-dislike").click(function() {
  var obj = $(this); //save $(this) to a variable so that you can use it in ajax success
  var liked = obj.data('type') == 'unliked' ? 'unliked' : 'liked';
  var image = obj.data('image');
  var user = obj.data('user');
  console.log(liked);
  console.log(image);
  console.log(user);
  obj.hide();
  obj.siblings('.like-dislike').show();
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="like-dislike" data-type="unliked" data-image="users-2" data-user="user-2" style="display:none;"><img src="unlovesm.png">unlovesm.png</div>
<div class="like-dislike" data-type="liked" data-image="users-2" data-user="user-2"><img src="lovesm.png">lovesm.png</div><br>



Note: you can have id's on your button, I just removed it to show simplified HTML structure
